# How to redirect from grails controller to relative url

Tags: grails

i have a problem with grails redirect from controller. 
F.e.

base url: `http://some.host/baseurl`
relative url: `/baseurl/controller/action`

And when I redirect from controller:
`redirect (url: relativeUrl)` 
it tries to load *http://some.host/baseurl/baseurl/controller/action*, not *http://some.host/baseurl/controller/action*.
As you can see it doubles **"baseurl"** part in url.

I haven't found any solution for this case.
How it can be solved?

Comment: Let Grails figure out what the URL should be and use `redirect(controller: 'controllerName', action: 'actionName')`.

Comment: Can't do this accurately. I have `backUrl` as string in params. And I need to follow it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this :

```
redirect(controller: "controllerName", action: "actionName")
```

**action (optional)** - the name of the action to use in the link, if not specified the default action will be linked

**controller (optional)** - the name of the controller to use in the link, if not specified the current controller will be linked

For more info :

**http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Controllers/redirect.html**